# Side effects of Spring Data Redis partial updates on key expiration

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm using Redis 5.0 with Spring Data Redis 1.8.7 and Jedis connector. I'm setting a TTL for my keys and my use case requires me to update properties of the objects I'm persisting without renewing the TTL, so I'm using [partial updates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.partial-updates) to achieve that.

I've noticed however that when I do a partial update the phantom copy created by Spring Data because of the TTL lags behind and does not include the updates. Another difference in behavior I've seen is that even though the phantom copy goes away when my key expires, it is not deleted when I manually delete a key **if** I've done any updates but it is deleted when no updates have been performed.

I'm not using key expiration notifications or secondary indexes at the moment, but I might in the future and I wonder if this is expected behavior when combining these two features and what side effects can occur because of their combined use.

Thanks!

Comment: The issue with missing phantom copy might relate to this bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-570

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @kara... I've since moved away from using a Repository for my implementation and am now using RedisTemplate because of this issue and the fact that I didn't need many advanced features...